# GeneralTransform: "Value does not fall within expected range"

Tags: silverlight-4.0, transform

We are trying to use a GeneralTransform like this:

```
 GeneralTransform gt = this.scrollViewer.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
```

We often, but not always, get the "Value does not fall withing expected range" exception.
Why does this happen, and is there some way to test the elements to know if the TransformToVisual() call will work?
Thanks for any insight...

Answer (score 0):

You can only call TransformToVisual on an element that is visible on the screen and already layed out.